# HTTP PUT request with Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra, httparty

I created a body for a PUT request with Ruby. When I print out the body, I don't see any problems. But when I try to print out the body from the actual PUT request, I start getting an error.

To elaborate, here is my code:

```
@data={param1: "nameserver",
       param2: {code: "XYZ", name: "NAME", start: "2017"}}

  puts "data = #{@data} " #This works fine

    @putResponse = HTTParty.put(base_url,  
                         :body => @data.to_json,
                         :headers => header)

    puts "putResponse.body is #{@putResponse.body}" #This is where I get the error
```

So as you can see, the line `puts "data = #{@data} "` works fine. It prints out

```
data = {:param1=>"nameserver", :param2=>{:code=>"XYZ", :name=>"NAME", :start=>"2017"}}
```

But the line puts `puts "putResponse.body is #{@putResponse.body}"` doesn't work. This is what it prints out:

```
putResponse.body is {"errors":[{"message":"The specified resource does not exist."}],"error_report_id":443}
```

So what's the problem here? (I'm using HTTParty to make my PUT request)

EDIT:

Here's how I got the host and header:

```
config = JSON.parse(File.read('config.json'))
puts "config: #{config}"

access_token = config['canvas']['access_token']
puts "access_token: #{access_token}"

host = config['canvas']['host']
puts "host: #{host}"

base_url = 'http://#{host}/api/v1/users/self/custom_data/program_of_study'
puts "base_url: #{base_url}"

header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' "#{$access_token}", "Content-Type" => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with `PUT` in Sinatra, is similar to dealing with `POST` - this is why the documentation may be scarce in this aspect.

This is a simple example of a Sinatra endpoint that receives `PUT` arguments from a `curl` request:

```
# server.rb
require 'sinatra'

put '/' do
  params.inspect
end
```

And test it with this curl command:

```
$ curl -X PUT -d n=hello http://localhost:4567/
```

The `params` hash will be available to you inside any Sinatra endpoint, including parameters received by any HTTP method.

In response to your comment, it is hard to debug without seeing your entire code. 
I suggest you run the tests provided in this answer, and gradually modify it to fit your actual code, to understand what breaks.

With the above `server.rb` running, the below test works without errors:

```
# test.rb
require 'httparty'

data = { 
  param1: "nameserver",
  param2: { code: "XYZ", name: "NAME", start: "2017" }
}

response = HTTParty.put 'http://localhost:4567/', body: data
puts response.body
# => {"param1"=>"nameserver", "param2"=>{"code"=>"XYZ", "name"=>"NAME", "start"=>"2017"}}
```

Comment: I actually changed up the description for this question to make it clearer. Could you please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'll add more information in the question regarding the header.

Comment: Alright I edited the question. Given the changes, do you think my this line of code is incorrect: `@putResponse = HTTParty.put(base_url,  
                         :body => @data.to_json,
                         :headers => header)`

Comment: No. It is likely that you are not properly defining the `/api/v1/users/self/custom_data/program_of_study` path in your Sinatra or that your request to it (`base_url`) goes to the real server and not your test server.

Comment: But is there any difference between writing it like this: `response = HTTParty.put 'http://localhost:4567/', body: data` and writing it like this: `response = HTTParty.put('http://localhost:4567', :body => data)`?